# How to identify the correct xpath within <span> tags within a larger <div>

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, xpath, web-scraping

The current project I'm working on deals with the "find_elements_by_xpath" command from Selenium. It's been going well, however I've been unable to identify the correct xpath for one area that's between span tags within a div tag. Here's the element I'm trying to get:

```
<div class="agencyAddress">
                    <span ng-show="x.agencyAddress1 != ' '" class="ng-binding">2115 W CHICAGO AVE </span>
                    <br>
                    <span ng-show="x.agencyCity != ' '" class="ng-binding">CHICAGO                       , </span>
                    <span ng-show="x.agencyState != ' '" class="ng-binding">IL</span>
this one here -->   <span ng-show="x.agencyZip != ' '" class="ng-binding">60622-7976</span>
                    <br>
                </div>
```

Everytime I try a different xpath, I get the "IndexError: list index out of range" exit code. I've tried a range of different xpaths, from copy and pasting the xpath when I rightclick in the inspect box, changing the [@id] section of the xpath, etc. My goal is to be able to scrape every area that has a zip code on the page, hence the "find_elements_by_xpath" command, so that's why I'm getting this specific exit code.

I greatly appreciate any and all ideas/ help. Thank you!

(For reference, here's the python code I have so far and the link to the website I'm scraping:

```
Zip_Code = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//* [@id="appSection"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/span[4]')
Zip1 = Zip_Code[0].text
Zip2 = Zip_Code[1].text
Zip3 = Zip_Code[2].text
Zip4 = Zip_Code[3].text
Zip5 = Zip_Code[4].text
Zip6 = Zip_Code[5].text
Zip7 = Zip_Code[6].text
Zip8 = Zip_Code[7].text
Zip9 = Zip_Code[8].text
Zip10 = Zip_Code[9].text
```

Link: https://insurance-agent.safeco.com/find-an-insurance-agency/app/search-results-locationSearch=60612 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able directly grab the zip code values using direct xpath like this,

```
//span[@ng-show='x.agencyZip != ' '']
or 
//span[contains(@ng-show,'agencyZip')]
```

Comment: The second one worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: @Alena glad to help. If it serves the purpose, please accept this as an answer by upvoting it. thanks